# Исправление ошибки в скрипте Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public KeyCode leftKey;
    public KeyCode rightKey;
    public KeyCode squatKey;
    public KeyCode jumpKey;

    public Animator animator;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", 0);
    }

     void Update() 
    { 
        float moveAxis = Input.GetAxis(moveInputAxis); 

        if (moveAxis != 0) 
        { 
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(moveAxis)); 

            Vector2 newVelocity = rb.velocity; 

            newVelocity.x = moveAxis * speed; 

            rb.velocity = newVelocity; 

            if (moveAxis < 0) 
            { 
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);   //flip character if going left  
            } else if (moveAxis > 0)   //if going right  
            {  
                transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);   //set the local scale to be facing right                                                      //set the local scale to be facing right  

            }  

        } else {   //if no input is detected then set speed to zero and play idle animation  

            animator.SetFloat("Speed", 0);  

        }  

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(jumpKey))
        {
            animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
            rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    
    }
}
```

[image: Ошибки]

как их исправить?

Comment: Не копипастить тупо теста кодов из интернетов и таких ошибок не будет. Учиться надо!

Answer (score 0):

Ну, наверное, добавить описание этой переменной туда же, где и остальные переменные класса вы объявляете - перед методами:

```cs
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    ...
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        ...
```

Comment: Мечешь бисер перед свиньями. Комментарии из скопированного в интернете кода не убрал. Скопировать строчку с полем класса, вероятно додумается, он не знает что такое поле или переменная, он умеет только копировать строчки.

Comment: @Yaroslav Для начинающего нормально копипастить код. Постепенно разберётся. Если захочет.

Comment: Нет не нормально. Писать годклассы начинающему самоучке нормально, так он сталкивается с проблемами и руку набивает, но для этого нужна хоть малейшие основы языка.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ты забыл объявить 3 переменных: переменную `rb`, которая отвечает за использование `Rigidbody2D`, переменную `speed`, отвечающую за скорость твоего героя и переменную `jumpForce` отвечающую за силу прыжка. Также не пойму зачем тебе переменная `rb2d`, если у тебя уже есть `rb`, выполняющая ту же самую роль.
2. В строке где ты объявил moveAxis написано что он равен `moveInputAxis`, такая строка в `Unity` не предусмотрена, вместо этого лучше написать `Horizontal`, также возьми во внимание что `Input.GetAxis` принимает **строку**, а не не существующую **переменную**.

Добавь эти строки в место где объявляешь переменные:

```
public float speed;
public float jumpForce;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
```

Значение `Input.GetAxis` измени на:

```
float moveAxis = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
```

В этой строке замени `rb2d` на `rb`;

```
rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```